# Optimizing Javascript function for Code Wars

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I have a solution for [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55143152820d22cdf00001bb/train/javascript) problem on [codewars.com](https://www.codewars.com) that works when I run it in my editor (All test cases on codewars that succefully complete pass), but when I try to submit, I get this error:

> Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete
>
> Why did my code time out?
>
> Our servers are configured to only allow a certain amount of time for your code to execute. In rare cases the server may be taking on too much work and simply wasn't able to run your code efficiently enough. Most of the time though this issue is caused by inefficient algorithms. If you see this error multiple times you should try to optimize your code further.

The goal of the function is to count from 1 to n and figure out how many numbers have a '9' in them. If there are multiple '9s' in a number for example 99, that munber has two 9s
This is the code I have now:

```
function number9(n){
  let numArray = [];
  let split = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    const split = i.toString().split("");
    if (split.includes("9")) {
      const joinArray = split.join("");
      numArray.push(...joinArray.split(""));
    }
  }
  let finalArray = [];
  for (let element of numArray) {
    if (element === "9") {
      finalArray.push(element);
    }
  }

  return finalArray.length;
}
```

I'm new to algorithms and trying to up my leetcode game. I do see nested loops (for example includes() in a loop) that can cause the inefficiency but I'm struggling to optimize it. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The last test, 10000000000, is a large number: 10 billion. Even an empty `for` loop to that number will run for too long. You will need to come up with a cleverer algorithm.

Comment: This is not an optimization issue, though your code could be much simpler. The key to that problem is figuring out a way to compute the number of 9 digits without having to check every single number in the range.

Comment: That said, optimization tips: 1. Don't `split` but use `charAt` to iterate over characters to avoid needless memory allocation. 2. No point putting all the numbers containing a 9 into an array, just keep a counter of the total.

Comment: @Thomas yes but that still won't pass the tests.

Comment: @Pointy See also my first comment :)

Comment: Consider: there is 1 "9" in numbers less than 10. There are 18 nines in numbers less than 100.

Comment: oops 20, not 18, actually it's a fascinating pattern

Comment: As Ponty says, this isn't solvable by looping every value between 0 and n since n gets too big. Think about the problem in a different way, Pointy is getting you in the right direction above ^^